# User Management / Session Management Plugin for Node

Tags: node.js

One thing I like about Django, Symfony, and most frameworks is they provide session management and user management:  the ability for users to create accounts, log in, etc.  Is there a package for Node.js that provides this?  I see Mongoose, but this looks more like a regular ORM.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Express/Connect have [session state middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/session.html) built-in; you just have to `use` it (along with the cookie parser).

```
app.use(express.cookieParser());
app.use(express.session({ 
  secret: 'make something up here!', 
  key: 'sid', 
  cookie: { secure: true }
}));
```

User/account management is something more opinionated; search npm for a module you like.  [passport](https://npmjs.org/package/passport) is popular.